# Adafruit display - отрисовка текста - Arduino Nano

Tags: c++, строки, память, текст, arduino

Пытаюсь отрисовать текст с помощью `Adafruit_GFX` и `Adafruit_SSD1306` Простые строки он выводит, но вот при таких условиях:

```
  display.clearDisplay();
  
  int t_h = 23;
  int t_m = 59;
  int t_s = 59;
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setCursor(0,8*2);
  display.println(String(t_h) + ":" + String(t_m) + ":" + String(t_s));
  
  display.display();
```

На дисплей выводится только: `:59`

Может быть я что то не понимаю в работе с микроконтроллерами и памятью или вообще есть способ рисовать текст из переменных на этом дисплее?

Comment: А что-то вроде strcat есть у микроконтроллеров? Развитие строк обычно идет 1. сналало простые ф-ции strcpy и strcat (они даже похожи `strcat(a,b) = strcpy(a+strlen(a), b)` грубо говоря). Более навороченая ф-ция sprintf, printf (форматированый вывод). А строковые классы - это уже приличное усложнение. Плюс важно что бы буфер позволял поместить строку нужного размера, и данный способ это позволяет.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в стандартной библиотеке Ardiono класс `String` довольно продвинутый, и поддерживает конкатенацию через перегрузку сложения.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел кастыль решение - отрисовывать переменные по порядку используя `display.print`
Теперь код выглядит так

```
  display.clearDisplay();
  
  display.setTextSize(2);
  
  display.setCursor(0,16);

  int t_h = 23;
  int t_m = 59;
  int t_s = 59;

  display.print(t_h);
  display.print(":");
  display.print(t_m);
  display.print(":");
  display.print(t_s);
  
  display.display();
```

Но я всё равно ищу ответ как можно избежать дальнейшего использования этого костыля

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `String()` формирует строку с завершающим нулем `('\0')`, и здесь:

```
display.println(String(t_h) + ":" + String(t_m) + ":" + String(t_s));
```

вы по факту передаете 3 строки, функция `println()` выводит последнюю из них.
Проблему можно решить разными способами, например сформировать строку до вызова функции `println()`, или попробовать такой код:

```
display.println(String( String(t_h) + ":" + String(t_m) + ":" + String(t_s)));
```